# codeigniter, php error - errot text problem

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework in my project.
I encountered php error.
English errors display well~
but, there are some odd texts that can not be readable.
like this...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: simplexml_load_file(http://localhost/uploads/seoul.kml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: ����� ��������κ��� ����� ��� �������� ���߰ų�, ȣ��Ʈ�κ��� ����� ��� ������ ������ϴ�.

Filename: controllers/editor.php

Line Number: 113
```

So, I think it's becase of text encoding~ .
My project's setting is utf-8(Korean)) in config/congif.php.

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

But, I can not find where I should put html utf-8 setting like this.

in application/error/error_php.php file, I can not find a place to put my utf-8 setting like this. because it's just div tags, no html header.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: <?php echo $severity; ?></p>
<p>Message:  <?php echo $message; ?></p>
<p>Filename: <?php echo $filepath; ?></p>
<p>Line Number: <?php echo $line; ?></p>

</div>
```

Or, is the crashed text is not a utf-8 problem?
any idea please~

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you cannot open the website and read from it. Is `allow_url_fopen` set to `On` in your PHP configuration?

EDIT

I was so quick I only saw the URL. Then the question is instead: Is the file readable?

Try:

```
<?php
$file = 'uploads/seoul.kml';

if ( file_exists($file) ) { 
  if ( is_readable($file) ) {
    print_r(simplexml_load_file($file));
  }
  else {
    echo "File is not readable";
  }
}
else {
  echo "File does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: If the file is local, not need to introduce a security issue by enabling url_fopen... just use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/seoul.kml' instead of http://localhost/uploads/seoul.kml (plus... didn't you miss the quotes around the URL?)

Comment: thank you for your answer ^^; but, yes I set allow_url_fopen to on already. and the file is readable~ I can access the file.

Comment: Did you try the code I gave you? The error message you get indicates that the file could not be read.